# mongoDB Aggregation and cursor - returning a promise that is not iterable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Given:

```
Node: 16.4.2
mongoose: 6.1.9
mongoDB driver: 4.2.2
mongoDB: 4.0.18
```

Using the `cursor` call to an aggregation query fails to produce the expected result and instead returns a promise. The aggregate query should return 30k records.

```
const cursor = Model.aggregate([{ $match: { ownerId: $someId } }]).allowDiskUse(true)
.cursor({batchSize: 100}); // type of ownerId is string
```

I have used variations on iterating through the cursor without any success.

```
cursor.next((doc) => {
     console.log('doc', doc);
})
```

Or

```
for await (const doc of cursor) {
     console.log('doc', doc);
}
```

Or

```
await cursor.eachAsync((doc) => {
     console.log('doc', doc);
});
```

Or

```
let doc
while ((doc = await cursor.next())) {
    console.log(doc._id)
}
```

Any feed-back is greatly appreciated!

Note: adding an `exec()` to the aggregate would result in the following:

```
const cursor = Listing.aggregate(query).allowDiskUse(true).cursor({batchSize: 100}).exec();

<rejected> TypeError: Listing.aggregate(...).allowDiskUse(...).cursor(...).exec is not a function
```

Comment: Can you share your schema?
also, can you specify what exactly is the value of $someId? it needs to be of type mongoose.Types.ObjectId

Comment: The schema is really not the issue imho. And I am using the simplified aggregate query as an example (the actual query uses lookups of multiple collections). Also, I have defined ownerId as a string and not an objectId (design decision). What I am asking is how do I iterate through the cursor.

Comment: your code seems correct. if you have the full example of what is not working I'm happy to look at it

Comment: @Zohar fixed it... has an `await` missing